# Android SharedPreferences Password

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences

I just wanted to ask if it is a good idea to store a password (encrypted) in the SharedPreferences.
In Android you can delete the sharedPredPref for an application and then the password is gone, so it is better to store it in a database like sqlite? In my application I saved it in a sharedPref, so when starts an activity for the first time, he must set a new password. Now the problem is that, someone else can just delete the sharedPreferences and then he will just asked again to set a new password.

Comment: Arent you more concerned about the security of the password than someone deleting it

Comment: Sry I didn't explain it properly. I have an acitivity which the user can put for example some notes or something else. These notes are stored in sqlite. The activity is password-protected. So if the user starts the app for the first time he must set a new password in order to access the activity. But if someone else wants to access it, he just need to delete the sharedPred and then he will be asked to set a new password again, without knowing the old password. If I store the password in a database and if the database is deleted then all the notes will be deleted and so the user cant see them

Answer (score 1):

In android `SharedPreferences` as well as `SQLite` are both cleared when in application screen you press `Clear data` button. So there is no difference in that!

The user in that case would be logged out just as the first time he starts the application. Final authentication should always happen at server-side, not inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is that someone might delete the preference xml file then storing them in SQLite will make no difference. Because both of these are deleted when you clear data for an app.

Comment: sqlite database wont be deleted when clearing the data of application from Settings.

Comment: Hmm, when developing I always use clear data to clear the DB, I'm not sure if the DB will be deleted, but the data in it will be wiped 100%.

Comment: @androidBeginner better to add the explanation in question itself nstead of comment.So it will be helpful for others to answer.

Comment: In this case both scenarios, SQLite and SharedPrefs are wrong for you. On a side note, you shouldn't rely on this type of authentication. A phone is a private device and you shouldn't really ask for password inside of the phone again. It's like making a second lock screen. It's a totally different scenario if you need to login remotely. Which is what I would recommend for you.

Comment: The SQLite database absolutely will be deleted when you clear data.

Answer (score 0):

Use MODE_PRIVATE in shared preferences so nobody can access it except your application

```
SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("yourpasspreference", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Better to save the password kind of thing in encrypted form.

To protect clearing the data from settings you can use this in your manifest

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
           android:manageSpaceActivity=".ActivityOfMyChoice">
```

It will Disable the Clear Data Button in Settings, Manage Space button will be shown instead which launches the `ActivityOfMyChoice` Activity defined by you.